# Bicep Burn While Doing Arm Circles

Tags: shoulders, biceps, curls

I'll do a set of bicep curls, then extend my arms (make a T shape), and do 2-300 rapid tight arm circles for my delts. I get the gnarliest bicep burn while doing the arm circles.

My question is, why do my biceps burn so good while targeting a different muscle group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The bicep is a bi-articular muscle crossing the shoulder as well as the elbow.

[This article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17196396/), "The role of the biceps brachii in shoulder elevation" summarizes what is going on here. It is paywalled, but the introduction is accessible and explains everything you need to know.

> These results clarify the role of the biceps in shoulder elevation, as a dynamic stabilizer, and suggest that it is a decelerator of the arm during the throwing motion.

Basically, the bicep crosses the shoulder and is working in some capacity while doing arm circles as a dynamic stabilizing muscle.

Comment: Thank you - great article. Body mechanics are amazing...so much there to learn.